# Find an atlas for special unitary group $SU(2)$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Define $$U = \begin{pmatrix}
              a+ib && c+id \\
              -c+id && a-ib
             \end{pmatrix}, \quad  \text{det}(U)=1.$$

Let $U'\subset\rm{SU(2)}$ be the subset of $U$ s.t. $a>0$. Let $\phi:U'\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3, \phi(U)=(b, c, d).$ For any element $U\in\rm{SU(2)},$ let $\xi_{U}(P)=\phi(U^{-1}P).$ Let $V_{U}$ be the domain of $\xi_{U}$.

I am told in class that it's possible to find an atlas that consists of 8 charts to cover $\rm{SU(2)}$. One is $(V_{U},\xi_{U})$. Ireally have not much idea about how to construct this atlas. But I'm wondering if it's helps to consider the 8 cases that $a,b,c,d>0,a,b,c,d<0?$

Comment: Note that $SU(2)$ and $S^3$ are diffeomorphic.

Comment: So is what I said correct?  I am thinking about something like covering $S^3$ since $u$ is 4-dimensional. But I am not sure how to wirte down the argument properly.

Comment: @Mindlack I know that $S^1$ and $S^2$ can be covered by two charts with stereoprographic, one is missing northpole, the other is missing southpole. Then can I say that there is an atlas for $SU(2)$ consists only two charts?

Comment: stereographic projection works for spheres in any dimension. So yes, you can write that.